# Problems with Adobe XD CC installation

Tags: drivers, adobe-xd

I downloaded and tried to install the free version of adobe xd cc and when I opened the installation wizard It read this message:

> Your machine's GPU is out of date. Drivers must support DirectX 3D DDI versions or above, and Intel drivers must have been released in 2014 or after

So I headed to the DirectX Diagnostic Tool and found the following information:

> Version: 8.15.10.2900
>
> Date: 11/26/2012
>
> Direct3D DDI: 10

What is the problem and is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: What make/model computer are you using? Does it have a discrete graphics card? If so, what make/model card is it?

Comment: @Cancun101 Intel(R) HD Graphics (Core i5)

Comment: What processor model is it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to install it in VirtualBox by any chance? (I've just had this issue for the past hour)

if you are using VirtualBox:

Disable 3D Acceleration under machine settings -> display -> Screen -> Acceleration -> (detick) Enable 3D Acceleration

Answer (score 1):

Intel(R) HD Graphics is legacy hardware and no longer supported.

You might find newer drivers at https://downloadcenter.intel.com for some versions of the card.
 You haven't given us sufficient information to be any more specific.

Comment: what are the details I should fill you in?