# Oracle VM windows 10 upgrade gpu-driver

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, adobe-xd

I have got a virtual machine using Oracle Virtual Box with windows 10. I need to use it for Adobe XD, which is only available for windows 10 and MAC OS. My host OS is Windows 8.1.

When I want to install Adobe XD, the installer only says:
"You must upgrade/update your system to install XD. Please check the following
-Your machine's CPU driver is out of date. Drivers must support DirectX 3D DDI versions 10 or above, and Intel drivers must have been released in 2014 or another"

I tried to upgrade my gpu-driver in the device-manager, but it says that I have the latest driver available.

I also tried to download the latest gpu-driver for windows 10 on the intel-website, but when I try to install it, this dialog pops up: (I downloaded the first driver [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28646/Intel-Graphics-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers?product=80939))

I am not very expearienced, so maybe it is a stupid mistake I have made, but I didn't find anything about it on the internet. I don't know if that is important, but I have installed the oracle guest extensions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your virtual box, you have to install the drivers for your virtual graphics card, which is done by installing guest tools.

Comment: As commented above but even I you do that I'm not sure it'll work. It won't if the software needs access to real, powerful GPU. Perhaps you should consider upgrading your host system instead. What's the point of keeping Windows 8.1? It's a dead end.

Comment: I have no idea why, but uninstalling the guest additions made it work.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution to run the GuestAddons alongside Adobe XD. You basically have to disable Direct3D:

```
Disable 3D Acceleration under machine settings -> display -> Screen -> Acceleration -> (detick) Enable 3D Acceleration
```

https://superuser.com/a/1404825/777972

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is VMBox Guest Add-ons, which modify the GPU interface drivers in order to make UI interface (like Resize Screen etc). Once you uninstall it, you'll be able to install Adobe XD. I couldn't find a way to use both Adobe and VMBoxGuestAddons at same time.